# Модернизация и плавная прокрутка ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть в xaml такая разметка:

```
<Grid Background="#2c2c2c">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True">
            <StackPanel Background="#FF1F1E1E" x:Name="ScrollPanel">
                <ListBox x:Name="favorites" Width="300" Background="#FF1F1E1E">
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 1" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 2" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 3" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 4" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 5" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 6" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 7" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
                <ListBox x:Name="library" Width="300" Background="#FF1F1E1E" Margin="0 20 0 0">
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 1" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 2" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 3" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 4" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 5" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 6" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Height="40" Background="#FF191919">
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 7" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу сделать плавную прокрутку (как, например, в браузерах). Но как видите, если обернуть всю мою конструкцию в `SrcollViewer`, то получится это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите вместо хорошего скроллбара, который бы крутил по пикселям всю длину `StackPanel` получается массивный скроллбар, который за одну прокрутку перемещает фокус в другой конец панели. Так вот, есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать так, чтобы он перемещался плавно? Еще было бы неплохо узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке колесом мыши в области, которая обернута в `ScrollViewer` происходил процесс прокрутки этого содержимого? (в обычной ситуации прокручивается только если навести на сам скроллбар и дальше уже колесом мыши)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Известная проблема.

```
CanContentScroll="False"
```

Насчёт прокрутки по элементам: ListBox сам внутри держит ScrollViewer, поэтому перехватывает прокрутку. Замени оба ListBox на ItemsControl (остальное можно даже не менять).

Comment: О, действительно работает. Я думал, что если поставить False, то тогда полоса прокрутки даже не появится, но, как говорится, я еще никогда так не ошибался. А вы не знаете насчет второго моего вопроса, про то, чтобы можно было прокручивать обернутый в ScrollViewer контент не наводя на сам скроллбар, а наводя на содержимое ScrollViewer?

Comment: @FirstSin Про CanContentScroll можно было бы прочесть в официальных доках, там вполне ясно написано про это. А вот насчёт прокрутки - я дополнил ответ.